# Dropping files inside gitignore path onto Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, binaryfiles

Each time I try to add a file to my resources which is in gitignore Xcode keeps telling me

"The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
res
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added"

So I add my resources by removing the res folder from gitignore, then dropping the file onto Xcode, and finally adding the res folder again to gitignore and removing any stage changes.

Is there a better way to do this procedure?

I'm keeping my res folder in gitignore because of too many binary files, otherwise the git folder would start to increase its size astronomically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them by using the `--force` flag on `add`:

```
git add -f res/foo
git commit -m "more resources"
```

(or by using wildcards, e.g. `git add -f res/*`)

Bonus tip: If you want to list the files that have been committed even though they match gitignore, you can do

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-standard
```

Comment: wouldn't that add the file to the .git folder anyway?

Comment: @rraallvv I'm not sure what you mean. The `.git` folder contains the Git repository, so in one sense copies of all version controlled files are stored there. Copies are first added when you `git add` the file. So, yes, it will be there too. And that's a good thing.

Comment: hmm, that is what I want to avoid, I usually remove the res folder from git ignore, drop the file onto Xcode and then run git checkout -- * to dischard any changes, then add res folder to gitignore again

Comment: never mind, I'll do that way, I don't know why my procedure is not working